# update a column using values from a different column of the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given the DB table:

```
CREATE TABLE stuff (
  id text not null,
  other text
);
```

That has lots of `id` values but has all `other` set to `NULL`, is there an elegant way to update the table so that all `other` rows get updated to `OTHER-{id}` (where `{id}` is the value of the `id` column)?

(It must work in Postgresql)

Comment: anyone mind explaining the downvotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only a simple `update` statement is needed with some string concatenation (`||`):

```
update stuff
   set other = 'OTHER-' || id
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the following:

```
UPDATE stuff
   SET other = 'OTHER-' || id;
```

`UPDATE` is the keyword used to identify which *table* you'd like to update.

`SET` is the keyword used to identify which *column* you'd like to update, and this is where you choose to assign the column to:

```
'OTHER-' || id
```

`'OTHER-'` being a string

`||` a shorthand way to concatenate

`id` the value you want.

Another way of writing this would be

```
other = concat('OTHER-',id);
```

I along with many others will find the `||` method to be much cleaner, but it's worth knowing about the dedicated function as well.